# Get a rolling order count into session data

Tags: google-bigquery

**I have the following table**

[image]

One client has two purchases in one session.

**My goal is to assign a order counter to each row of the table.**

To reach this goal I am using the lag function to call the last order_id and the last order_timestamp:

```
SELECT 
lag(event_timestamp) over (partition by session_id order by
ecom_data.order_id) as prev_order_timestamp,  
lag(ecom_data.order_id)
over (partition by session_id order by event_timestamp) as
prev_order_number 
From table
```

My desired output is this:

[image]

Problem, I do not get the previous order time. Instead I get the event_timestamp from the previous event.

My second challenge is that I do not know how to assign a order_count. My desired output is this:

[image]

Ideally, this order count should be rolling as in the real data set I dont know how many orders in total each session had. There can be 0 - infinite orders.

Can you help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
### create sample table (helps to introduce these in your questions)
WITH
  base AS (
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:17:41") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'ts' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:17:42") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:27:14") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'atc' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:27:15") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'p' AS event_name,
    123 AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:30:47") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:30:50") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:31:01") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'atc' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:31:20") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'ts' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:31:22") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'rv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:31:32") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:31:35") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:32:49") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'p' AS event_name,
    456 AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:33:35") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:33:48") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'tv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:33:50") AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:31:50") AS event_timestame
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'p' AS event_name,
    123 AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 10:33:50") AS event_timestame
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'C' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 11:13:50") AS event_timestame
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'C' AS client_id,
    1 AS session_id,
    'pv' AS event_name,
    NULL AS order_id,
    DATETIME("2022-05-12 11:33:50") AS event_timestame),

  prev_order1 AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS prev_order_number1
  FROM
    base),

  ### filling in order number using your requested output
  prev_order2 AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(prev_order_number1) OVER(partition by client_id ORDER BY event_timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS prev_order_number2
  FROM
    prev_order1
  ORDER BY
    event_timestamp )

### inserting order_counter logic
SELECT
  *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by client_id ORDER BY prev_order_number2) - 1 AS order_counter
FROM
  prev_order2
```

Think about edge cases and perhaps if you want to partition by other dimensions such as client_id vs total table (as you have it now). I included client_id = B as an example.

[image]

Comment: Hey Yev, thank you so very much for your reply and support! The solution works perfectly with the test data set. However if I convert it to my real data set strange results appear...so i am curretnly still figuring out if my real data set is buggy. One error for example is: I have a session switch but the order number from the previous clients session is attached to the other clients session, though they are not related. Also this order id then gets set for 5 other unrelated client sessions and is not even updated in a row with a new order number.

Comment: so at what level do you want this order counter to be established? total (all rows, like you have now) OR client id only OR client id + session ?

Comment: per your comment I adjusted my answer and now included additional sample of client_ids to my dummy data, you will see edge cases that might break your logic under client_id B which wouldnt register a purchase

Comment: Hey, the mistake was really in the dataset on my end. So the solution you gave is perfect. I simply added the partition on session_idand it worked perfectly. Again, thank you so much!